# Alternate method for setting size of input textbox?

Tags: html, css, ios, width, rounded-corners

Basics of CSS for rounded corners [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8251358/1054225).

Update:  In order to render my textbox consistently across iOS/BlackBerry/Android, the only successful way was NOT to use size=# or =#em or =#%, but to set the width of the input to be width: ###px .  When I do that (inline or in CSS) it wrecks the rounded corners effect.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

I have determined that setting the width attribute is what breaks the corners.

My question: Is there another way to set the width attribute?  I'm open to another idea of how I can render the size of the textbox consistently cross-platform?

Comment: Pixel perfection is unrealistic, and if youre design breaks if it isn't rendered identically across devices then you may want to go back to the drawing board. Hopefully you find a viable solution, but I would still think about the impossibilities of pixel perfection and perhaps consider being a little more flexible. http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Can you provide the code? In a fiddle?

Comment: Do websites need to look exactly the same in every browser? No.  Am I looking for pixel perfection? No. Do I need my textbox to be a usable size across three major platforms... yes.  Not sure what the fiddle is, but I linked to the code above.

Comment: I guess I should add that setting the width breaks it on all platforms, not just one.  I am looking for suggestions as to other "flexible" solutions.  If I can't have rounded corners, that's life... but I thought surely other people have experienced this and might have suggestions.

Comment: @Dallas--This is a fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/hQshV/ (as Jason requested and based off the code you directed us to). The site jsfiddle allows people to go and "fiddle" with the html, css, and javascript to see if things can be made to work. Great tool. Now, the code you posted above does not yield a look like what you posted above.

Comment: I have seen other jsfiddle links, but didn't quite realize what it was. Very cool tool! Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQshV/3/) . I notice that in desktop Safari if I use the Safari-iOS 4.1-iPodTouch User Agent, it renders OK, but what is interesting is that using my actual iOS 4.1 iPod (as well as BB emulator(9800) and a physical Android (Samsung GTI9000M)) appears with the corners broken, as seen above.

Comment: Correction... I went to check again and the corners are fine on Android, BB and using Safari's User Agent spoofer, it's just the physical iOS devices(iOS3/4) where it happens.  Haven't teted 5 yet.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I read somewhere that there can be issues if the radius is more than half the height, so I decreased radii and boom... the problem disappeared.

Comment: If making sure that your radius is smaller than half the height solved it, then you should post that as an answer yourself and accept it (so that this question does not remain "unanswered").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by decreasing the radius of the rounded corners (see comments)

Answer (score 0):

No, size is set only by the attribute `size=` which is unreliable so you can only use the css attribute `width: 50px`

Comment: You are right about it being unreliable. I tried to set width both inline and in CSS and said that in the question.